# Is there a universal linux/unix startup script to append to?

Tags: linux, sh

After researching, it seems that it would be easier to add commands to an existing script as opposed to creating a startup script for each of my needs. I am trying to get a series of repititive tasks done at system startup like:

```
sudo mkdir -p ~/scripts

sudo mount -t vboxsf scripts ~/scripts
```

Instead of finding a methodology for each system (I read that start script vary from system to system), I would like to know if there is a universal scripts to append this too (like I have done with environment variables in `/etc/environment`). Is there a universal file I can target to do these mounts?

Thanks, Yucca

Comment: Several distributions have a skeleton script for *services* (e.g. `/etc/init.d/skeleton` on Debian etc...) but I don't think you'll find one for your own *scripting* needs. And these two goals are really different, because a service program should always run and usually don't end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some distributions (Redhat/CentOS) have /etc/rc.local exactly for this task. On openSuSE it is /etc/init.d/after.local

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at initd
http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/